# Parse Exception: At line 1, column 0: no element found

Tags: java, xml, android, parsing, httpurlconnection

I have a weird issue. I receive the following error that causes a force-close:

> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:508)
>   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:467)
>   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:329)
>   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:286)

After clicking the Force Close button, the Activity is recreated and the parsing completes without a hitch. I'm using the following code snippet inside doInBackground of an AsyncTask:

```
URL serverAddress = new URL(url[0]);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
connection.connect();

InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

xr.parse(new InputSource(stream));  // The line that throws the exception
```

Why would the Activity force-close and then run without any problems immediately after? Would a BufferedInputStream be any different? I'm baffled. :(

Thanks for your time everyone.

Update: It turns out HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() returns -1 every so often, so the InputStream probably isn't being correctly set.

Comment: Looks like the stream is null, can you dump the contents of it to System.out.println with commons IOUtils?

Comment: Is this a copypaste? `HTTPURLConnection` != `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: That was a typo, HttpURLConnection fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HTTPURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Those lines are a bit odd. Is it `HTTPURLConnection` or `HttpURLConnection`? The default request method is already `GET`. The `setDoOutput(true)` will however force it to `POST`.

I'd replace all of those lines by

```
URLConnection connection = serverAddress.openConnection();
```

and retry. It might happen that it returned an error because you forced `POST` and didn't write anything to the output (the request body). The `connection.connect()` is by the way already implicitly called by `connection.getInputStream()`, so that line is superfluous as well.

**Update**: does the following for testing purposes work?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC, extremely informative. Will make the changes and give it a shot.

What is interesting, is that most of the time the XML parses without a hitch. It's almost a luck of the draw to have an exception thrown...though it seems to happen frequently enough to be a problem.

Comment: After making the changes, the force-close behavior still exists. It seems like the parser isn't parsing anything. Hooking up with the debugger to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Regarding the update, that should work, but I think System.util.Log is utilized instead of System.out in Android. Will test and update the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I dont' know if you fixed this, but I had the same problem. It was weird, it would work fine in the emulator, but then on the phone, it was always giving me the `xr.parse()` error. Even when I printed the `InputStream` it would give me legitimate output of the xml document. It seemed the problem was in the creating of the `InputSource` object

Here's how I fixed it: instead of using `InputStream` to create your `InputSource` I just created input source from the url string directly.

```
InputSource a =  new InputSource(url_string);
```

where url_string is just a string with your url. Don't ask me why it works...I dont really like it, as there's no way to check for timeouts and things like that it seems. But it works, let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think it will work specifically for my case, because I need to use HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(). I've temporarily fixed the issue by checking the response code and retrying the connection if the code is -1. Your input may help others though!

Answer (score 1):

Per `InputStream` javadoc the method will block until the data is available or the EOF is encountered. So, the other side of Socket needs to close it - then the inStream.read() call will return.

If you use `BufferedReader` , you can read in a line-by-line manner. The `readLine()` method will return as soon as a line from HTTP response is read.

Comment: Thank you ring bearer, will look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

On a related design note, loading up contents of a URL should never Force Close an activity - I recommend putting all this into an AsyncTask implementation and report or retry after you are back on the GUI thread.

Comment: Agreed. The code snippet in the original post resides in doInBackground of an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue.
I was first using the `InputStream` in `Scanner` to print the content of it.
And then trying to pass it in XML parser.

The problem was that I was not closing the `Scanner` object. And using the `Inputstream` in parser.

After closing the scanner object, I was able to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and could make no sense of it because I was parsing directly from the InputSource.  When I modified the code to pull the result into a string before the xml parse, I found out the problem was simply a mispelled web service method name and that the error message reported by that service was the killer.