# Problems with org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException

Tags: android, inputstream, saxparser

My SaxParser implementation throws sometimes a

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
```

Exception. At the next attempt it works perfectly good. 
In general there is no problem with the internet connection.

Here is my implementation.

1) base class for all parser

```
public abstract class BaseFeedParser{

    private final URL url;
    private InputStream is;

    protected BaseFeedParser(String url) {
        try {
            this.url = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected InputStream getInputStream() {
        try {
            this.is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            return is;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected void closeInputStream() throws IOException{
        if(this.is!=null)
            this.is.close();
    }
}
```

2) a example parser

```
public class Parser extends BaseFeedParser {

    public void parse() {
        RootElement root = new RootElement("xml");
        //additional 
        Element child = root.getChild("child");
        child.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {          
            @Override
            public void start(Attributes attributes) {
                // do something....
            }
        });

        try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root
                .getContentHandler());

            closeInputStream();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }   
    }
}
```

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: I think [this is very related to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716063/parse-exception-at-line-1-column-0-no-element-found)

Comment: Thanks Reno for your comment, I have read this answer, but it does not help. I'm not using POST and if the parser get its data, it can parse them successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was not the XML-Parser, but the buggy implementation of NSURLConnection. I switched to HttpClient and the problem vanished.

More infos here: [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and here: [HttpURLConnection responsecode is randomly -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066738/httpurlconnection-responsecode-is-randomly-1)