# HttpURLConnection responsecode is randomly -1

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Hi I'm using following code to establish a url connection. But randomly I get the responseCode -1 (which is the default value of responseCode):

```
  try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            handleData(new DataInputStream(httpconn.getInputStream()), requestCode);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "HttpConnection not OK: " + httpconn.getResponseCode());
            ActivityHelper.httpError(this);
        }
        httpconn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "handleHttpConnection", e);
        ActivityHelper.httpError(this);
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because it works perfectly in estimated 9 of 10 attempts.

Comment: I'm guessing `url.openConnection()` doesn't necessarily have time to open underlying http connection. You could try adding `httpconn.connect()` after opening it. Or response code should be set latest once you have called `httpconn.getInputStream()` which could be moved before checking response code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UrlConnection is buggy.

See [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) blog post from the official Android Developer's blog for a pre-Gingerbread workaround for one problem.

My advice, don't use it. It was still being flaky for me on 3.2. I switched to HttpClient and things have been less bad.

Comment: Anyone have an update on this, or a confirmation on flakiness for the 4.x platforms?