# What is the preferred network library on Android 4.x that handles redirects?

Tags: android, networking, redirect, httpurlconnection

HttpURLConnection on Android works great 99% of the time.

It was recommended as the preferred networking class here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

I'm having trouble with the 1% of the time that it seems to be flaky, mentioned by others here, but on Android 4.2.2: [HttpURLConnection responsecode is randomly -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066738/httpurlconnection-responsecode-is-randomly-1)

When the server sends a 301 Moved Permanently, a response code of -1 is returned 9/10 times.

1 - Has anyone else had this problem?

2 - Is HttpURLConnection still the preferred networking system to use?

Comment: Chuck can't control a 301... tried a Roundhouse kick?

Comment: I had read the same blog as you before, and had decided to switch from httpclient to httpurlconnection. So far, I do not have any problem with Gingerbread and onward.