# Android responseCode 400 if Android-version lower than 4

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-2.2-froyo, android-version, http-response-codes

somebody knows why I get the ResponseCode 400 on android 2.x ? In Android 4.x it works and the server returns 200.

```
        URL url = new URL(url_in);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        url = uri.toURL();
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");

        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();
```

Where is the difference?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your issue is, but 2.x had a different implementation of HttpURLConnection than 4.x does. On 2.x, it's recommended to use HttpClient, while on 4.x, HttpUrlConnection is recommended. Also, why do you convert from a URL to a URI and back to a URL again? Why not just use the first value of the url?

Comment: sorry Url and uri was just a leftover.. of a test.

ok if found this post... 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8067181/1847899 

and this.. (topic: Avoiding Bugs In Earlier Releases) 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067181/1847899).

and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)..

topic: Avoiding Bugs In Earlier Releases