# Http connection response is 400 in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send the email through Amazon server as a Raw mail. I have implemented this application in Java its working properly. But if i use same code in android i am getting 400 as error Please any body suggest me how to get correct header for http request?

```
                       String dataBytes = encodedReqPayload;
                       dataBytes=URLEncoder.encode(encodedReqPayload,"UTF-8");

                      uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
                      uc.setRequestProperty("Host", "email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
                     // uc.setRequestProperty("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                      uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                      uc.setRequestProperty("x-amz-date",date_1);
                      uc.setRequestProperty("X-Amzn-Authorization",str);
                      uc.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf8 ");
                      uc.setDoOutput(true);
                      uc.setDoInput(true);
                      uc.setUseCaches(false);
                       uc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5);
                       uc.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(dataBytes.length());
                       uc.usingProxy();


                      uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                      uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + dataBytes.getBytes().length);
                      uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                      //uc.setRequestProperty("Body",""+dataBytes);
                      uc.setUseCaches(false);
                      uc.setDoInput(true);
                      uc.setDoOutput(true);
                      uc.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
                      uc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066738/httpurlconnection-responsecode-is-randomly-1/8067181#8067181
Btw, why do you have this line? uc.usingProxy();  P.S. Try stripping your lines until you will have basics Help: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: I have gone through the every basic configuration but still i getting 400 as error. Is there any device related issues in connecting amazon simple email server?Same code with code converter is replaced in java working fine!. please any one help me on this issue

Comment: Code converter? what code converter?

Comment: if you believe that there is a device related issue, then try emulators