# org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found

Tags: java, android, logcat

I'm getting an error in my logcat stating:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
```

Does anyone know what this means or a common method of resolving it? (I can post my source code if need be - but I'd rather not if possible - it's a bit lengthy and I'm not sure exactly where the issue is stemming from.)

LOGCAT:

```
09-05 18:45:10.275: D/CLIPBOARD(7511): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
09-05 18:45:15.370: D/dalvikvm(7829): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 48K, 43% free 3084K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 33ms
09-05 18:45:15.405: D/dalvikvm(7829): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 43% free 3084K/5379K, external 1K/513K, paused 29ms
09-05 18:45:15.460: D/dalvikvm(7829): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 43% free 3090K/5379K, external 2167K/2538K, paused 25ms
09-05 18:45:15.465: I/System.out(7829): Sim State5
09-05 18:45:15.470: D/Network Availability(7829): CONNECTED
09-05 18:45:15.470: D/Network Availability(7829): NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: apnChanged, extra: wap.new, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-05 18:45:15.535: D/CLIPBOARD(7829): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
09-05 18:45:23.890: D/ICCID(7829): 8901260832120867967
09-05 18:45:23.890: I/System.out(7829): ICCID%1234 = 587
09-05 18:45:23.895: I/System.out(7829): ICCID/1234 = 7213339410146570
09-05 18:45:23.955: D/dalvikvm(7829): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 20K, 42% free 3129K/5379K, external 2664K/3205K, paused 60ms
09-05 18:45:24.005: I/url...(7829): https://wapgate.testurl.com/REST/phoneSettings
09-05 18:45:24.080: V/httpPost(7829): org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@40538700
09-05 18:45:38.380: D/dalvikvm(7829): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 132K, 42% free 3284K/5575K, external 4561K/5679K, paused 65ms
09-05 18:45:47.375: I/System.out(7829): response....org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40520c58
09-05 18:45:47.375: V/response...(7829): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40520c58
09-05 18:45:47.390: V/In the parser(7829): now
09-05 18:45:47.390: W/System.err(7829): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
09-05 18:45:47.395: W/System.err(7829):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:550)
09-05 18:45:47.395: W/System.err(7829):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:480)
09-05 18:45:47.395: W/System.err(7829):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
09-05 18:45:47.395: W/System.err(7829):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
09-05 18:45:47.395: W/System.err(7829):     at com.new.example.datasettings.XmlParserHandlerFinal.getQueryResponse(XmlParserHandlerFinal.java:176)
09-05 18:45:47.395: W/System.err(7829):     at com.new.example.datasettings.UpdateActivity.success(UpdateActivity.java:535)
09-05 18:45:47.400: W/System.err(7829):     at com.new.example.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onPostExecute(UpdateActivity.java:490)
09-05 18:45:47.400: W/System.err(7829):     at com.new.example.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onPostExecute(UpdateActivity.java:1)
09-05 18:45:47.400: W/System.err(7829):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-05 18:45:47.400: W/System.err(7829):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-05 18:45:47.405: W/System.err(7829):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
09-05 18:45:47.405: W/System.err(7829):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 18:45:47.410: W/System.err(7829):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-05 18:45:47.410: W/System.err(7829):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
09-05 18:45:47.410: W/System.err(7829):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 18:45:47.410: W/System.err(7829):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-05 18:45:47.410: W/System.err(7829):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
09-05 18:45:47.415: W/System.err(7829):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
09-05 18:45:47.415: W/System.err(7829):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 18:45:47.455: E/dalvikvm(7829): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.new.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.showNotification
09-05 18:45:47.455: W/dalvikvm(7829): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 17 (Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;) in Lcom/new/example/datasettings/ConfigFinalActivity;
09-05 18:45:47.455: D/dalvikvm(7829): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0035
09-05 18:45:47.455: D/dalvikvm(7829): VFY: dead code 0x0037-007f in Lcom/new/example/datasettings/ConfigFinalActivity;.showNotification ()V
09-05 18:49:24.780: I/dalvikvm(8028): Debugger is active
09-05 18:49:24.945: I/System.out(8028): Debugger has connected
09-05 18:49:24.945: I/System.out(8028): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:49:25.150: I/System.out(8028): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:49:25.350: I/System.out(8028): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:49:25.555: I/System.out(8028): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:49:25.740: I/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:49:25.750: I/dalvikvm(8028): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:49:25.750: I/System.out(8028): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:49:25.955: I/System.out(8028): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:49:26.155: I/System.out(8028): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:49:26.355: I/System.out(8028): debugger has settled (1429)
09-05 18:49:26.735: D/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:49:33.745: I/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:49:33.750: D/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:49:33.750: I/dalvikvm(8028): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:49:52.295: I/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:49:52.300: D/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:49:52.300: I/dalvikvm(8028): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:49:54.490: I/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:49:54.495: D/dalvikvm(8028): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:49:54.495: I/dalvikvm(8028): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:50:09.285: I/System.out(8135): Sending WAIT chunk
09-05 18:50:09.285: W/ActivityThread(8135): Application com.new.example.datasettings is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-05 18:50:09.315: I/dalvikvm(8135): Debugger is active
09-05 18:50:09.485: I/System.out(8135): Debugger has connected
09-05 18:50:09.485: I/System.out(8135): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:50:09.685: I/System.out(8135): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:50:09.890: I/System.out(8135): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:50:10.090: I/System.out(8135): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:50:10.295: I/System.out(8135): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:50:10.495: I/System.out(8135): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:50:10.690: I/System.out(8135): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-05 18:50:10.895: I/System.out(8135): debugger has settled (1478)
09-05 18:50:12.270: D/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:50:16.850: D/dalvikvm(8135): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 43% free 3084K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 89ms
09-05 18:50:16.885: D/dalvikvm(8135): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 43% free 3085K/5379K, external 1K/513K, paused 26ms
09-05 18:50:16.955: D/dalvikvm(8135): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 43% free 3091K/5379K, external 2167K/2538K, paused 27ms
09-05 18:50:17.670: I/System.out(8135): Sim State5
09-05 18:50:18.455: D/Network Availability(8135): CONNECTED
09-05 18:50:18.460: D/Network Availability(8135): NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: apnChanged, extra: wap.new, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
09-05 18:50:19.280: I/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:50:19.290: D/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:50:19.290: I/dalvikvm(8135): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:50:27.560: D/CLIPBOARD(8135): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
09-05 18:50:51.050: D/ICCID(8135): 8901260832120867967
09-05 18:50:51.055: I/System.out(8135): ICCID%1234 = 587
09-05 18:50:51.055: I/System.out(8135): ICCID/1234 = 7213339410146570
09-05 18:50:51.095: D/dalvikvm(8135): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 19K, 42% free 3131K/5379K, external 2664K/3205K, paused 27ms
09-05 18:50:51.145: I/url...(8135): https://sitwapgate.new.com/REST/phoneSettings
09-05 18:50:51.275: V/httpPost(8135): org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@40538e28
09-05 18:51:09.480: D/dalvikvm(8135): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 133K, 42% free 3285K/5575K, external 4561K/5679K, paused 67ms
09-05 18:51:12.770: I/System.out(8135): response....org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40522f48
09-05 18:51:12.770: V/response...(8135): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40522f48
09-05 18:51:12.805: V/In the parser(8135): now
09-05 18:51:12.815: W/System.err(8135): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
09-05 18:51:12.820: W/System.err(8135):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:550)
09-05 18:51:12.825: W/System.err(8135):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:480)
09-05 18:51:12.825: W/System.err(8135):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
09-05 18:51:12.830: W/System.err(8135):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
09-05 18:51:12.835: W/System.err(8135):     at com.new.example.datasettings.XmlParserHandlerFinal.getQueryResponse(XmlParserHandlerFinal.java:176)
09-05 18:51:12.835: W/System.err(8135):     at com.new.example.datasettings.UpdateActivity.success(UpdateActivity.java:535)
09-05 18:51:12.845: W/System.err(8135):     at com.new.example.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onPostExecute(UpdateActivity.java:490)
09-05 18:51:12.845: W/System.err(8135):     at com.new.example.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onPostExecute(UpdateActivity.java:1)
09-05 18:51:12.850: W/System.err(8135):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-05 18:51:12.855: W/System.err(8135):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-05 18:51:12.855: W/System.err(8135):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
09-05 18:51:12.860: W/System.err(8135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 18:51:12.865: W/System.err(8135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-05 18:51:12.865: W/System.err(8135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
09-05 18:51:12.870: W/System.err(8135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 18:51:12.870: W/System.err(8135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-05 18:51:12.875: W/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
09-05 18:51:12.880: W/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
09-05 18:51:12.880: W/System.err(8135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 18:51:12.940: E/dalvikvm(8135): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.new.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.showNotification
09-05 18:51:12.940: W/dalvikvm(8135): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 17 (Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;) in Lcom/new/example/datasettings/ConfigFinalActivity;
09-05 18:51:12.940: D/dalvikvm(8135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0035
09-05 18:51:12.940: D/dalvikvm(8135): VFY: dead code 0x0037-007f in Lcom/new/example/datasettings/ConfigFinalActivity;.showNotification ()V
09-05 18:51:22.920: I/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:51:22.930: D/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:51:22.930: I/dalvikvm(8135): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:51:23.080: I/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:51:23.095: D/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:51:23.095: I/dalvikvm(8135): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:51:36.135: I/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:51:36.150: D/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:51:36.150: I/dalvikvm(8135): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 18:52:01.560: I/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-05 18:52:01.570: D/dalvikvm(8135): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-05 18:52:01.570: I/dalvikvm(8135): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118567/xml-parsing-using-sax-parser-getting-org-apache-harmony-xml-expatparserparseexc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980588/problems-with-org-apache-harmony-xml-expatparserparseexception

Comment: Checked both links... issue is not the same

Comment: My guess is that the xml you're getting from https://wapgate.testurl.com/REST/phoneSettings is malformed or has an unexpected character encoding. Try checking those out to pen point the issue.