# Openweathermap API - org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found

Tags: android, android-xml, saxparser, weather-api, openweathermap

I am trying to parse Openweathermap API using the SAX parser `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml`. But I am getting the above error when I set `xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));`.

The code for getting xml-

```
URL url = new URL(target_URL);

                HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.connect();

                if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == conn.getResponseCode()){
                    SAXParserCustom saxParserCustom = new SAXParserCustom();
                    saxParserCustom.parse(conn.getInputStream());

                }
```

This is how I am parsing the XML file using SAX.

```
XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

        SAXHandler saxHandler = new SAXHandler();

        xmlReader.setContentHandler(saxHandler);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String s="";
        while ((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            stringBuilder.append(s);
        }
        Log.d("SAX", stringBuilder.toString());

        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
```

The above log is printing the xml file correctly so my guess is I am doing something wrong with the parse function.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980588/problems-with-org-apache-harmony-xml-expatparserparseexception

Comment: @Haresh saw the question and answer. The answer suggests that the problem was a buggy HTTP connection which returns -1 but I check for status code 200 before trying to get inputStream. Also my log is printing the xml correctly. 

If I oversaw anything, please point it out.

Comment: lol, it works as expected ... just think about InputStream as the stack if you pop it via BufferedReader there is no data on stack anymore ...